# how to do dataframe operations with rolling std deviation of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a code that takes a `rolling std()` of `moving_average_period` for a given column `df.loc[:,columnNames[sma_iter]]` with the following line of code:

`rolling_std = df.loc[:,columnNames[sma_iter]].rolling(moving_average_period).std()`

This is stored into  `rolling_std` as a `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`.

So I want to multiply each row in `rolling_std` with a different column in the same `df` with the same index (date) and save the output as a different column:

```
df[bb_high] = df.loc[:, columnNames[sma_iter]] + (rolling_std * 2)
df[bb_low] = df.loc[:, columnNames[sma_iter]] - (rolling_std * 2)
```

However I'm getting an error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

How should I be doing this?

Comment: can not reproduce your problem maybe df['bb_low'] = df.loc[:, columnNames[sma_iter]] - (rolling_std * 2)

Comment: @Wen thanks, the whole code is [here](https://codeshare.io/2EVREK) if you want to copy and paste it